# Angular 5: How to display array of objects in html by *ngFor

Tags: html, arrays, angular5

I have array of objects as below:

app.component.ts:

```cpp
this.documents=[
  { employees: [ {name: "John Smith", age: 28},
                 {name: "Sarah Johnson", age: 32},
                 {name: "Mark Miller", age: 46} 
               ]
  },
  { employees: [ ] },
  { employees: [ {name: "Jimmy Colleen", age: 35},
                 {name: "Olivia Powell", age: 37}
               ] 
  },       
]
```

app.component.html:

```cpp
         <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Age</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngIf="documents.length">
              <tr *ngFor="let doc of documents; let i = index">
                <td>Department {{i + 1}}</td>
                <td>Name {{}}</td>
                <td>Age {{}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

My question is how to display different names and their ages for each department in HTML. I've googled this issue but didn't get the suitable answer.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention any department name in your code. I added some department names to populate data.

Example code:

**app.component.ts**

```
documents = [
    { employees: [ {name: 'John Smith', age: 28, department: 'IT'},
            {name: 'Sarah Johnson', age: 32, department: 'IT'},
            {name: 'Mark Miller', age: 46, department: 'IT'}
        ]
    },
    { employees: [ ] },
    { employees: [ {name: 'Jimmy Colleen', age: 35, department: 'ADMIN'},
            {name: 'Olivia Powell', age: 37, department: 'ADMIN'}
        ]
    },
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th scope="col">Department</th>
       <th scope="col">Name</th>
       <th scope="col">Age</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <ng-container *ngIf="documents.length">
      <tbody *ngFor="let doc of documents; let i = index">
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of doc.employees;">
          <td>{{employee.department}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: The department is just named by index. It doesn't have property into array. Anyway, it doesn't show anything on interface :/. The table is blank.

Comment: Thank you, it works partially, cause I wanna display each department employees details without multiple department in different row. How could I show this?

Comment: i modified my code, check now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g8dmif

Comment: Great, thanks @sdn404. Besides, I have another array of strings I want to display next column by putting *ngFor, but apparently it cannot accept two array at the same time. Which solution is available ? Thank you for helping me this last time :)

Comment: create a new array with the data from your existing arrays and then iterate by *ngFor. That is the easiest solution i am thinking right now.